# "FileNotFoundError" when importing Image from PIL on Google Colab

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I want to import an image on Google Colab from PIL. By doing so:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('smallhouse.jpg')
img
```

However, I get this error.

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-20-8ab03a99a9db> in <module>()
      1 
      2 from PIL import Image
----> 3 img = Image.open('smallhouse.jpg')
      4 img

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2807 
   2808     if filename:
-> 2809         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2810         exclusive_fp = True
   2811 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'smallhouse.jpg'
```

Not sure why. Thanks!

Comment: Check your working directory - you may have to navigate to where "smallhouse.jpg" is located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** You must upload the `smallhouse.jpg` image to your **Google Drive**.

**2.** In your `.ipynb` file, you need to include this code at the beginning of your application: `drive.mount('/content/gdrive')`.

Go to the **URL** provided. Then, you will be prompted to give permission to access your Google Drive. Copy the code provided, access your application and paste the code there.

**3.** Finally, you can pass your image's path, which now is: `/content/gdrive/My Drive/smallhouse.jpg`.

Your code will look something like this:

```
# Imports
from google.colab import drive
from PIL import Image

# Mount Google Drive for fast, responsible access to files
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

# Open image
img = Image.open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/smallhouse.jpg')
img
```

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!